# Bilingual dictionary grouping and adding entries

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am new at xslt, but fascinated by the possibilities. I am revising a bilingual dictionary file.

The dictionary file consist of `<items>`. Each `<item>` has an entry `<trefw>` within an entry cluster `<trefwcl>` (which contains grammatical info (`<gramt>`), labels), a translation cluster `<vertacl>` and an example cluster `<voorbcl>`.

To some `<item>` elements I have manually added sorting information `(@sorteer)`.

I transform the file with the help of a number of separate xslt files.

One of these xslt operations generates items without entry word but with a `<voorbcl>` which later on need to be placed at a given entry word. Some of these desired entries do not yet exist.

For this purpose, I generated with a separate xslt file dummy items with entry words derived from the `@plaatsbij`. The generated dummy item merely consists of an `item` containing a `trefwcl` and a `trefw`.

This method works but creates double items, when the entryword already exists.

The next step is to place the newly formed `<voorbcl>` items with their appropriate items.

All of this works, but I run into some problems I cannot solve.

*My questions*

1. The first problem is that the file contains double items with the same entry word: [1] the newly created dummy item and [2] extant items. (Other double items occur when the form of e.g. nouns coincides with adjectives, etc.)
2. The second problem is that while joining the `voorbcl` at their desired places works, the @sorteer attribute disappears. The reason is obviously that I introduce a new item, but do not know how to transfer the extant attribute to the item.
3. The third problem is that my current stylesheet groups extant items with the same entry `trefwcl/trefw` regardless of word type

Ideally I would like to have an xslt file which combines the steps indicated here:

1. create only new dummy items when there are no extant items
2. add examples (voorbcl) preferably to existing items, rather than the dummy items.
3. preserve attributes in the item node.
4. only group items when the entries `trefw` are of the same word class `(<gramt>)`, e.g. noun, adj.

Can you help me out with this? Thank you in advance.

Robert

INPUT

```
<items>
  <item>
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>fél</trefw>
         <redopm>dummy item</redopm>
      </trefwcl>
   </item>

    <item sorteer="foo">
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>fél</trefw>
         <gramt>adj</gramt>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>fel</verta>
      </vertacl>
   </item>

   <item>
      <voorbcl plaatsbij="fél">
         <voorb>ze zien fél mit mekaar</voorb>
         <vvert>ze houden van elkaar</vvert>
      </voorbcl>
   </item>

<item sorteer="green">
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>gruun</trefw>
         <gramt>adj</gramt>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>green 1</verta>
      </vertacl>
   </item>


<item>
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>gruun</trefw>
         <gramt>noun</gramt>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>green 2</verta>
      </vertacl>
   </item>

</items>
```

The xslt file I use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="eg" match="voorbcl" use="@plaatsbij"/>

<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="trefwcl/trefw">
            <item>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <trefwcl>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="trefwcl/trefw"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="trefwcl/label"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="trefwcl/vorm"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="trefwcl/gramt"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="trefwcl/objsub"/>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="trefwcl/redopm"/>
                         <xsl:copy-of select="trefwcl/redla"/>
                </trefwcl>

                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="vertacl"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="voorbcl"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
             <xsl:copy-of select="key('eg', current-grouping-key())"/>
            </item>
</xsl:for-each-group> <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>-->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Present output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>fél</trefw>
         <redopm>dummy item</redopm>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>fel</verta>
      </vertacl>
      <voorbcl plaatsbij="fél">
         <voorb>ze zien fél mit mekaar</voorb>
         <vvert>ze houden van elkaar</vvert>
      </voorbcl>
   </item>
 
   <item sorteer="green">
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>gruun</trefw>
         <gramt>adj</gramt>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>green 1</verta>
      </vertacl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>green 2</verta>
      </vertacl>
   </item>
</items>
```

The desired output:

```
<items>
    <item sorteer="foo">
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>fél</trefw>
         <gramt>adj</gramt>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>fel</verta>
      </vertacl>
      <voorbcl plaatsbij="fél">
         <voorb>ze zien fél mit mekaar</voorb>
         <vvert>ze houden van elkaar</vvert>
      </voorbcl>
   </item>

<item sorteer="green">
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>gruun</trefw>
         <gramt>adj</gramt>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>green 1</verta>
      </vertacl>
   </item>


<item>
      <trefwcl>
         <trefw>gruun</trefw>
         <gramt>noun</gramt>
      </trefwcl>
      <vertacl>
         <verta>green 2</verta>
      </vertacl>
   </item>

</items>
```

Comment: I don't understand your description. You are grouping items by `trefwcl/trefw`. There are two items with `trefwcl/trefw` = "gruun". Why should they not be grouped? What exactly sets them apart?

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is the grammatical information: the one is a noun, the other an adjective. They should not be grouped. The grouping on trefwcl/trefw is too rough.

Comment: What about the dummy item that is neither? Should it be grouped nevertheless or should it simply be discarded? I don't see that it contributes anything to the output.

Comment: The dummies that serve no purpose should be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

1. Properly, you should ask only one question at a time;
2. I think (!) the following addresses the main issues you have raised - at least the output seems to be identical to the expected one;
3. If I am guessing (or rather continuing to guess) correctly, you want to add an instruction to copy "dummy" items that do not have a corresponding "real" item.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="eg" match="voorbcl" use="@plaatsbij"/>

<xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item[not(trefwcl/redopm='dummy item')]" group-by="trefwcl/concat(trefw, '|', gramt)">
            <item>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/@*"/>
                <trefwcl>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="trefwcl/(trefw, gramt)"/>
                </trefwcl>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/(vertacl, voorbcl)"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('eg', trefwcl/trefw)"/>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each-group> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried it, but got this error: Type error at char 32 in xsl:for-each-group/@group-by on line 9 column 122 of test2.xsl:  XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the third argument of  fn:concat() (<gramt/>, <gramt/>) in built-in template rule for /items in the unnamed mode. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the third argument of fn:concat() (<gramt/>, <gramt/>). To my understanding the syntax is correct and the file I run it against is valid.

Comment: What are you using to test this? You can see my code working with your input here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVK6D4d

Comment: I use Saxon-HE 9.8.0.4J. I will try the link. Thank you!

Comment: I solved the problem. In one item there were two gramt nodes.

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks great!

Comment: I am sorry, Martin, I found out that the stylesheet apparently only connects the voorbcl to existing items. The voorbcl that should connect to the dummies have disappeared, as well as the dummies themselves. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: 1. My name is not Martin. 2. I struggled very hard to understand your requirements. I suggest you post a separate question regarding each additional problem you face. I also recommend simplifying the example when you do that.

Comment: I am very sorry about misreading your name. I am not a programmer, but a linguist, doing his best in this area.